# VBA - How to insert Horizontal Line in Outlook TaskItem

Tags: vba, outlook, rtf

I want to insert an horizontal line, eg., before a text in a TaskItem body. It is possible to do this using Insert menu and clicking the horizontal line button on symbols group. But, how to code this?

This is what I've tried:

```
Sub NewTask()

 Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem

 Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

 With objTask

        .Subject = "Example Task"
        .Body = ??What to put in here?? & "Example Body"
        .Save

End With

Set objTask = Nothing

End Sub
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910256/how-to-add-horizontal-rule-to-outlook-using-macro) show how to reach this for Mails. As far as I know, MailItem have Html body property whereas TaskItem does not have.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452200/write-html-code-inside-of-task-body-in-outlook) related post?

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you need to use the [TaskItem.RTFBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property which returns or sets a byte array that represents the body of the Microsoft Outlook item in Rich Text Format.

The code for a horizontal line is the following:

```
\pard \brdrb \brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20 {\fs4\~}\par \pard
```

To set up the RTF formatting in Outlook you may use the following code:

```
.BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
.Body = StrConv("your RTF string", vbFromUnicode) 'Convert RTF string to byte array
```

---

Be aware, The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can u show me how to set RTFBody? I tried: `objTask.RTFBody = StrConv("{\pard \brdrb \brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20 {\fs4\~}\par \pard}")` and also `System.Text.Encoding.AsciiEncoding.GetString("{\pard \brdrb \brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20 {\fs4\~}\par \pard}")` without luck. Thanks again

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but there is no `.BodyFormat`  property available for `TaskItem`. Should I set this property in other object?

Comment: I tried this: `objTask.RTFBody = StrConv("{\pard \brdrb \brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20 {\fs4\~}\par \pard}", vbFromUnicode)` and I got a runtime error. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reach the solution through RTFBody. However the Word object model approach, pointed by Eugene Astafiev, helped me to solve the issue.

First of all: **Add reference to Word library** in VBA Editor, Tools, References

And this is the example sub working:

```
Sub NewTask()

 Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
 Dim objInsp As Inspector
 Dim objDoc As Word.Document
 Dim objSel As Word.Selection

 Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
 Set objInsp = objTask.GetInspector
 Set objDoc = objInsp.WordEditor
 Set objSel = objDoc.Windows(1).Selection

 With objTask

        .Subject = "Example Task"
        objSel.InsertAfter "Example Body"
        objDoc.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard
        .Display
        .Save

End With

Set objTask = Nothing
Set objInsp = Nothing
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objSel = Nothing

End Sub
```